# Building BERT tokenizer with custom data

Tags: bert

I'm wondering if there is a way to train our own Bert tokenizer instead of using pre-trained tokenizer provided by huggingface?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, it is possible, but that implies that you need to train again the whole model, not only the tokenizer.

[Here](https://huggingface.co/blog/pretraining-bert) you can find the steps to do everything with the HuggingFace libraries, including a complete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I got what I want.